# when i use global in php I have a error, why?

Tags: php

I don't know if i am using it rightly

this is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /Users/*/test.php on line 10

and this is my php code :

```
$q[0] = "ahmad";
$q[1] = "mohammed";
$q[2] = "khaled";


function content(){

    global $q[2];
    $s =$q[2];  
}

content();
echo $s;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: change the global to global $q;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it! The reason is that you cannot set specific key in array as global, also you also have to set $s as global.

```
$q[0] = "ahmad";
$q[1] = "mohammed";
$q[2] = "khaled";


function content() {
    global $q;
    global $s;
    $s = $q[2];
}

content();
echo $s;
```

Comment: Oh. Someone upvoted it. A shame.

Comment: I'm aware that you shouldn't use global, but that's what this guy tried to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `global` on single array values, only whole variables:

```
function content(){
    global $q;
    $s = $q[2];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use global. Pass it through your function as a parameter. Using `global`is usually bad practice.

```
$q[0] = "ahmad";
$q[1] = "mohammed";
$q[2] = "khaled";


function content($param){
    return $param[2];  
}

echo content($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only make `$q` global and you can still acces it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Only the $g should be get from the global scope.

```
function content(){
    global $q;
    $s =$q[2];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **`global`** of `$q` & `$s`. Something like this

```
    <?php

$q[0] = "ahmad";
$q[1] = "mohammed";
$q[2] = "khaled";


function content(){

    global $q,$s;
    $s =$q[2];
}

content();
echo $s;

?>
```

Comment: have you checked your code.. it contains errors

Comment: @komal, No errors. Instead it printed blank output. Modified the code now and thanks for pointing it out.